# Evaluate partially applied function

Tags: haskell

I'd like to implement an index structure as follows:

```
f :: [String] -> String -> Maybe Int
f haystack needle = Map.lookup needle m
  where m = Map.fromAscList $ zip (sort haystack) [1..]

g :: String -> Maybe Int
g = f ["123", "456", "789", ......]
```

Every time I evaluate `g str`, the map `m` needs to be newly computed.

What's an elegant way to avoid that?

I feel like I'm missing some terminology here. What's the concept I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use a lambda:

```hs
f :: [String] -> String -> Maybe Int
f haystack = \needle -> Map.lookup needle m
  where m = Map.fromAscList $ zip (sort haystack) [1..]
```

Or go pointfree:

```hs
f :: [String] -> String -> Maybe Int
f haystack = flip Map.lookup $ Map.fromAscList $ zip (sort haystack) [1..]
```

But for your specific function,  you can do even better:

```hs
import Data.List (elemIndex, sort)

f :: [String] -> String -> Maybe Int
f haystack = fmap (+1) . flip elemIndex (sort haystack)
```

Comment: I'm completely missing why the map wouldn't be recomputed in all three versions. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Fascinating, I had expected (at least) the lambda version equivalent to the original version. I suppose there's no more robust, idomatic way to express `f`? Do you have some specific resource you'd recommend as intro for the topic? Thanks!

Comment: @arrowd: As an optimisation (`-ffull-laziness`, on by default), GHC *tries* to lift `where`/`let` bindings like `m` out of a lambda like `\ needle -> …`, but it isn’t *guaranteed*; if you want guaranteed sharing, the placement of `where`/`let` bindings is how you make it explicit. Here, we’re replacing `\ h n -> let m = … in …` with `\ h -> let m = … in \ n -> …`. That is, `f` applied to `h` returns a function with `m` in its closure, which can be applied to multiple `n`s without recomputing `m`. Also, GHC uses the number of parameters on the left of `=` as an arity hint for when to inline.